# model can save strong params in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, model

I make a method to save the parameters of the controller in the model, but I can not include them in the model, what is the syntax to do the create
I used

In the controller

```
Product.create_product(product_params, @user)
```

and in the Model

```
def self.create_product(params [:name, :portions, :whashed], user)
```

but this method don't save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using this code:

In controller:

```
product = Product.new(product_params) #product_params is a function that return a hash with details of product
product.user = @user # or current_user if you are using Devise gem
product.save!
```

If you want to do it your way, then you can try this

In Product Model

```
def self.create_product(product_params,user)
  product = Product.new(product_params)
  product.user = user
  product.save!
end
```

And in controller:

```
def create #Method corresponding to your action
  Product.create_product(product_params, @user)
end

private

def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :portions, :whashed) #Assuming you are using form_for tag
end
```

Comment: I used user for other parameter thar I need

Answer (score 0):

```
      @product = Product.new(product_params)    
   @product.save           
  @kind = Kind.where(user_id: user).last
  @product.update(kind_id: @kind.id)
```